# Como colocar uma imagem de carregamento dentro de uma função JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java

Eu tenho essa função abaixo:

```
function consultarOcorrencia(number, sequence){
    form = document.forms[1];

    form.number.value = number;
    form.sequencial.value = sequence;

    form.submit();

}
```

Depois do `submit`, uma Java Action é chamada.

```
@Override
    public ActionForward perform(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response) throws ApplicationException, SystemException {

        MyForm myForm=  (MyForm ) form;

        MyDelegate.getInstance().cancel(myForm);

        return mapping.findForward("cancel");
    }
```

É possível que enquanto a função estiver sendo executada, colocar um gif de carregamento?

Como este:

[image]

Esta tarefa pode levar até 7 segundos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer via ajax em vez de submit, chama seu loading antes do processamento ajax e depois vc esconde ele.

Aconselho você a usar a lib BlockUI, muito boa e facilita muito.
[BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/)

No caso de você precisar usar o submit, você pode fazer um bem-bolado, chama o loading antes do submit(), assim da impressão que esta processando e esse loading some quando o submit completar e renderiza a nova pagina.
ficaria algo assim

```
function consultarOcorrencia(number, sequence){
    //Aqui chama seu loading
    $.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img src="loading.gif" /> Aguarde...</h1>' });

    form = document.forms[1];

    form.number.value = number;
    form.sequencialAvaliacao.value = sequence;

    form.submit();

}
```

Comment: Agradeço, mas nesse caso específico eu tenho que usar JavaScript puro.

Comment: Então na linha que coloquei o blockUI, você chama seu loading.

Comment: Eu não estou sabendo como chamar essa imagem , tentei como nesses links http://www.pcurtis.com/popup.htm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211244/display-image-as-popup-on-page-load você tem alguma idéia de como chamá-la ?

Comment: Muito obrigado, consegui utilizar a biblioteca do JQuery no projeto.

Comment: JQuery é sensacional, depois veja essa lib BlockUI, vai te ajudar muito. abracos

Comment: Obrigado mesmo !

Answer (score 4):

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
var loader = document.getElementById('loader');

loader.style.display = "block"; // Mostra o loader, utilize quando a função começar

setInterval(function() {
  loader.style.display = "none"; // Esconde o loader, utilize quando a função terminar de executar.
}, 9000);
```

```css
#loader {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img id="loader" src="http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/loading.gif">
```

Comment: Uma dúvida, como usar dessa forma na minha function ? muito obrigado !

Comment: @EdsonCezar, você pode utilizar no começo da sua função consultaOcorrencia, agora para esconde-la você precisa analisar quando você recebe o retorno do java de que todo o procedimento foi executado, isto poderia ser um success, você esta utilizando ajax?

Comment: Não posso utilizar ajax nesse sistema, esse é problema.

Comment: @quando você entende que o procedimento acabou ?

Comment: Apenas com o retorno da Action, esse está sendo meu problema.

Comment: Coloquei o exemplo da Action na minha pergunta.

Comment: @EdsonCezar sinceramente eu não entendo bem do java e como você poderia resolver isto, eu particularmente utilizaria o ajax para no retorno dele esconder, não indico muito o que vou te falar agora mas se você souber em media o tempo que esse metodo irá demorar para executar você podera colocar um setInterval com a quantidade de tempo, mas não é recomendado...

Comment: Eu consegui, usando a função abaixo, mas muito obrigado pela sua resposta !

Comment: @EdsonCezar Maravilha, que bom que conseguiu resolver o seu problema ;)

Comment: Obrigado @Highlander

Answer (score 4):

Eu utilizo a seguinte implementação:

```js
var block = document.querySelector(".block");
var fazerRequisicao = document.getElementById("fazerRequisicao");

fazerRequisicao.addEventListener("click", function () {
  //bloquear tela antes de iniciar a requisição.
  block.classList.remove("hidden");

  var htmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  htmlRequest.open("GET", "http://apps.testinsane.com/rte/status/200/5", true);
  htmlRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (event) {  
    if (htmlRequest.readyState == 4) {
      if (htmlRequest.status == 200) {
        alert("Requisição realizada com sucesso");
      } else {
        alert("Ocorreu um erro durante o processamento");
      }
      //desbloquer a tela ao termino da requisição.
      block.classList.add("hidden");
    }
  });
  htmlRequest.send();
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none; 
}
.block {
  background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.3);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px white;
  z-index: 1234567;
}

.block img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  
  -webkit-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
}

@-ms-keyframes rotating {
  from { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-moz-keyframes rotating {
  from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotating {
  from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-o-keyframes rotating {
  from { -o-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { -o-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes rotating {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<input id="fazerRequisicao" type="button" value="Fazer Requisição" />
<div class="block hidden">
  <img src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/svg/81/81948.svg"/>
</div>
```

no exemplo acima, estou realizando uma requisição assincronia (AJAX) que demora 5 segundos, ao termino dela a tela é desbloqueada.

No seu caso, você está realizando uma requisição síncrona, então não é necessário desbloquear a pagina (a menos é claro que você cancele a requisição).